# jQuery setInterval - проблемка с циклом внутри

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, асинхронность, setinterval

Есть страница с ячейками, в которые нужно постоянно обновлять значения, путь к которым лежит на других страничках. Всего на данный момент 24 окна. Вызывается скрипт прямо перед body:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>  
  <head> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  ......
  <script type="text/javascript" src="myjquery.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Если сделать так:

```js
   jQuery(function() {
         jQuery.ajaxSetup({
           cache: false
         });
         setInterval(
           function() {
             var arrFiles = ["Descr/Descr1.htm", ...];
             var arrCells = ["#Сell1_1", ...];
             for (var i = 0; i < 23; i++) { 
             //23 специально сделано для теста
               jQuery.get(arrFiles[i], function(result) {
                 jQuery(arrCells[i]).text(result);
               });
             }
           }, 1000);
```

то получается, что сначала пробегает цикл, отправляет запросы, а потом начинает получать ответы, но так как переменная i=24 в этот момент, все ответы поочередно соответственно начинают складываться в ячейку 24, остальные остаются мёртвыми.

Если же сделать так:

```js
       jQuery(function() {
             jQuery.ajaxSetup({
               cache: false
             });
             setInterval(
               function() {
                 var arrFiles = ["Descr/Descr1.htm", ...];
                 var arrCells = ["#Сell1_1", ...];
                   jQuery.get(arrFiles[0], function(result) {jQuery(arrCells[0]).text(result);});
                   jQuery.get(arrFiles[1], function(result) {jQuery(arrCells[1]).text(result);});
                   ...
                   jQuery.get(arrFiles[23], function(result) {jQuery(arrCells[0]).text(result);});
               }, 1000);
```

то всё хорошо работает.

Не хотелось бы использовать такие громоздкие конструкции, а заставить работать 1-ый вариант...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939032/jquery-pass-more-parameters-into-callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо на каждой итерации захватывать текущее значение счетчика:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 23; i++) { 
  //23 специально сделано для теста
  jQuery.get(arrFiles[i], (function(iter) {
    return function(result) {
      jQuery(arrCells[iter]).text(result);
    };
  })(i));
}
```

Comment: вроде заработало, медленно правда всё это как-то... Пойду разбираться как этот код работает

Comment: @Михаил - Медленнее, чем Ваши 24 строчки?

Comment: по ощущениям - да, хотя может проблемы с сетью....

Answer (score -1):

Сдесь запросы посылаються. Цыкл For закончил свою работу.

```
jQuery.get(arrFiles[i], function(result) {
      jQuery(arrCells[i]).text(result);
});
```

Ошибка внутри функции ответа:
Замени arrCells[i] примерно вот так:

```
jQuery.get(arrFiles[i], function(data) {
    jQuery(data.arrCells).text(data.result);
});
```

Переменная data должна вернуть объект результата JSON:

- № ячейки куда записать значение;
- значение;

Внутри ответа, Вы не должны ссылаться на изменяющиеся переменные извне.

Comment: Ворошить бэкенд для этого? И откуда ему знать какой у него `i` в цикле?

Comment: что-то не заработало так... Насколько я понимаю она скопом все ответы свалит в массив arrCell?

Comment: Это ж Ваш запрос. 
В ответ Вы можете запихнуть что угодно. Я написал что для этой задачи Вам нужно вернуть  № ячейки куда записать значение;
- значение;